# Open from application HTTPS-page in browser with auto authentication

Tags: java, android, https, webkit

As the internet html-form, run POST to https://anysite.net/do.aspx?.... (httpS)

Form include fields: login, password, domain, etc.

I know target page, values of login, password, domain, etc.

I need to make auto-complete this page in Android app and go to new page in default browser.

In analyzing this I burn four questions:

1. How to programmatically open source page in the default browser page (webkit) with a "fill-in" fields?
2. How to programmatically open a new page (target for the html-form) in the default browser with the "accepted" fields? Attempts to HttpsURLConnection, SSLContext, or etc. have failed, the browser behaves as if no values ​​fields login, password, domain ... In which way to see?
3. How to do the same, but without opening page in browser and with recording source page in the file/string?
4. As having the string with html-code a new page, "push" it to the default browser, with the installation of session cookies etc. SSL (TLS) variables?

I will be happy references to working examples of the subject!